# How do i link my navigation page from sub folders properly

Tags: html, w3-css

I have tried linking my navigation page but it's  not working... The codes are right I  guess. 
I used the [link](/folder/jupy.Html)
But if i remove the page from the sub folder  it will link properly. 
Help pls

Comment: Difficult to understand what you're asking here, but in case you want to link to the parent folder, use `../`